# BottomNavigationItem doesn't adopt the material theme jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-bottomnav

I am migrating my app to jetpack compose and the theming and styling is giving me some headache.
I have implemented Bottom Navigation as explained in this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#bottom-nav).
I have also set the background color as such:

```
backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
```

but the bottom navigation items don't react to changes. The selected item is not highlighted.
My expectation was that the material theme would be applied automatically.
I am using Material 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My Problem was that I was using `BottomNavigation` and `BottomNavigationItem`.
I switched to `NavigationBar` and `NavigationBarItem` and the design is now adjusted based upon the `MaterialTheme`.

Answer (score 2):

The `backgroundColor` parameter defines the background color for the `BottomNavigation`. If you want to change the background color of the `BottomNavigationItem` you can use the `background` Modifier in each item.

Something like:

```
BottomNavigation (
    backgroundColor = Yellow
) {
    items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        BottomNavigationItem(
            modifier = if (selectedItem == index) Modifier.background(Red) else Modifier,
            selectedContentColor =  White,
            unselectedContentColor = Gray,
            //...
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that BottomNavigation background defaults to *primarySurface*,

```
//From docs  
backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface
```

but if you're using the lightColorScheme/darkColorScheme it doesn't let you set that attribute in your theme.
You'll have to override the backgroundColor in BottomNavigation to match the colorScheme attribute you want. You might also want to change "selectedContentColor" in BottomNavigationItem to the onColor version of the background (unselectedContentColor defaults to a medium alpha version of whatever selectedContentColor is)